# Adding a scroll pane to a panel within a panel

Tags: java, user-interface, jpanel, containers, jscrollpane

My code is essentially as follows

```
JPanel x = new JPanel();
JPanel y = new JPanel();
JPanel rowPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(y);
Container c = frame.getContentPane();
rowPanel.add(x, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
frame.add(rowPanel);
c.add(scrollPane);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

except that its in a for loop to create a lot of those in a gridlayout on the frame. The thing I want to do is put that scroll pane in the rowPanel as center but I'm pretty sure I have to add the scroll pane with the container and I don't know how to specify to the container to add the scroll pane there

Answer (score 0):

So as it turns out I don't have to add the scroll pane with a container, I can add it directly to the panel by just puttting

```
rowPanel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```